# How to decide Cluster size and type of instance to be used in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to decide the cluster size, the number of nodes, type of instance to use and hardware configuration setup per machine in HDFS? If possible please explain how it can be done for 10 TB of data.
e.g. if we have 10 TB of data, what should be the standard cluster size, number of nodes and what type of instance can be used in hadoop?

Comment: What do you mean by "type of instance"? If you're talking about AWS or other cloud, you shouldn't be using HDFS for persistent storage... Also your answer depends on what you want to **do** with your servers, not just on data size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been Hadooping for a few years now. First, check out this Hortonworks guide:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_cluster-planning/content/ch_hardware-recommendations_chapter.html

Some personal notes:

- Bare minimum, depending on replication factor of 3, you need about 50TB (10x3=30TB  80% rule: 40TB usable, this give you 8TB to work with ) - So 5 Nodes at 10TB a piece for HDFS
- HDFS can only use a maximum of 80% of total cluster space
- More nodes = faster YARN jobs
- Hive & PIG can read compressed data as if it was uncompressed
- I'd personally start with 5 nodes, 3 for a zookeeper quorum and 2 can be assigned NameNodes
- All of them can be set to DataNodes
- Don't forget about an Ambari server, and make this a VM...you'll need backups and snapshots daily
- Upgrades/updates can blow stuff up, always have a plan if a job fails
- Sometimes the most basic install doesn't go as planned ;)
- **Start small and scale out! Hadoop is built on this type of thinking!**

---

**TLDR:**
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_cluster-planning/content/conclusion.html

**5 Nodes at 10TB a piece for HDFS**

Comment: With HDP now being released on Hadoop 3, that 3x storage rule doesn't apply anymore with Erasure Coding

Comment: That's very interesting, although I would still avoid anything above 2.6.4 for production uses. Anything that's bleeding edge usually isn't that reliable ;)

Comment: True. By the way, you forgot to mention YARN services in the answer and the memory requirements for squeezing all these services into only 5 machines (plus a VM)

Comment: Ya, I think if he sticks to the guide (24 GB to 48 GB of RAM minimum per node) he should be fine. Although, he hasn't responded or been specific about what he's doing lol

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am she and not he.
Thanks @Petro for the explanation. I have checked the link you provided and it was helpful.

Comment: @Sudha I'm glad a could help, please mark the answer correct and let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please elaborate on your comment, if we are using AWS instance, HDFS shouldn't be used for persistent storage

Comment: @Sudha EMR or other cloud providers will use S3 or other object storage. HDFS is very expensive on EBS volumes when compared to S3

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you so much. 
I am new to hadoop and still trying to learn these concepts. I have no further question.